# linkchecker ignore multiple urls

Tags: linkchecker

I would like to not check the url's that contain this:
gitlab.forge.stanis.fr
rosetta-store.rd.stanis.fr

I have tried several things in the conf file like this:
[filtering]
ignore=
gitlab.forge.stanis.fr
rosetta-store.rd.stanis.fr

but I get "Error parsing configuration" errors
thank you in advance

i not understand how work the linkcheckerrc regex file:
https://github.com/wummel/linkchecker/blob/master/config/linkcheckerrc

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the following to your linkchecker command line in order to skip checking URLs containing those domains:

```
--ignore-url=gitlab\.forge\.stanis\.fr --ignore-url=rosetta-store\.rd\.stanis\.fr
```